# Is it impractical to open a sqlite database with SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY?

Tags: database, sqlite

SQLite explicitly supports the use case of a single writing thread and multiple reading threads. In my application a single thread writes to the database, but multiple threads (created in response to API requests) can query the database concurrently.

But it seems to me than since SELECT statements cannot run while there is a hot journal, everyone must open the database with SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE. Is there any point to SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY?

Comment: You'll likely need the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` flag for databases that cannot be written to, either due to permissions or because the database is on a read-only medium like a CD. The "reader" threads need write access because they may have to roll back a journal left behind by a crashed writer.